# Partial object on HTTP GET

Tags: rest, api, architecture

We have collection of documents:

```
class Document {
id;
title;
someContent;
creator;
...
}
```

Need to implement REST API which in first case, return all documents with all fields ("id", "title", "someContent", etc.).
In second case, return all documents but only part of fields (only "id" and "title").

Which way is the best to do it? Is it good idea to implement it in one endpoint with query param "field"? Or is it better to separate them to different endpoints? 
Also can I use 206 status code for it?
Is there any "best practice" to implement this functionality?

For example I can do it like this (but I don't sure that it's right way):

```
GET /documents (200 status code)
GET /documents?field=id&filed=title (206 status code)
```

Hence, "field" is optional query param which just indicates fields we need to return.

In first Get, all fields would be returned. As example: `[{id: "5F1AB3", title: "Document 1", creatur: "John", ...}, {...}]`. 
In the second, JSON with only two fields: ID and title. Response looks in this way: `[{id: "5F1AB3", title: "Document 1"}, {...}]`.

Answer (score 0):

> Which way is the best to do it?

You probably want two different resources, in much the same way that a full sized image and a thumbnail are different resources.

If they are different resources, then we should expect to see two different identifiers.

Notice that this is exactly what you would want, as a client, if you were trying to bookmark the resource, or share your bookmark with somebody else.

```
GET /documents
GET /documents?field=id&field=title
```

Those identifiers are fine.  REST cares very little about the spelling conventions you use to distinguish one identifier from another.  Note that the query is part of the identifier -- as far as general purpose components are concerned, these are two different identifiers, the two resources may not be related to one another at all!

[206 Partial Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1) is not a good idea; the semantics of `206` are coupled to [Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233), which isn't a good fit for what you are doing.